# Passing a boolean value using event function to styled component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I have a styled input component like so

```
 <InputFields isFilled={e=>SignInData[e.target.name]!==''} type="text" name="Username"  onBlur={e=>handleChange(e)} />
```

As u can see I am passing in a custom prop isFilled in my component. This currently doesn't work because I require boolean in my interface in the styled component and if I try to pass on boolean I couldn't use the event(e=>***) or so. Is there some way I can tell my styled component to check the name of my component and use that to check the key in my state value. I am also open to any better suggestions to pass on a boolean if an input is empty to my component in a more reusable way.Also, here is my state handlers.

```
  const [SignInData, setSignInData] = useState({Username:'',Password:''}as StringKeyValue)
  const [Update,setUpdate] = useState(false)
  const handleChange:CallableFunction = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    SignInData[e.target.name]=e.target.value
    setSignInData(SignInData)
    setUpdate(!Update)
  }
  useEffect(() => {}, [Update])
```

Comment: It took me a lot of courage to ask a question again on stack. I am very new to this experience please go easy on me. And I also currently just not use the name attribute and straight up use isFilled={SignInData.Username!==''} and it works fine. Just wanted a more universal and short component.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to do here, so you want to pass in a prop to your custom component <InputFields > telling it if it's current value is an empty string or not?

Comment: Yes exactly thats what I want to do its working for me when I hardcode it, but I want to pass in the value dynamically(and something that can be used more universally) as my components rerender anyways whenever any input is changed.

Comment: in your custom component you'd have something like this <input value={variable} onChange={handleChange} /> where variable is either a local state to the component or a prop coming from it's parent component. Either way instead of passing down a prop called isFilled you'd use the variable value inside your custom component instead of the isFilled. I'm not sure if I made sense so show your entire component code if you want me to elaborate more

Comment: Yes I totally understand what u mean, so I still need to specify the key value for each and every input. I just wanted to get the name attribute I am already writing for my input to be used as the key for accessing the value in my state.

Comment: you mean you want to access the name passed to the <InputFields > inside the InputFields's code? then you'd use props.name ... if this is not your question try and explain the end goal you're trying to achieve in your <InputFields >

Comment: OK So what im Trying to achieve is something like <InputFields value={MyStateJSON[props.name]} name="MyKey">